# MS Access: Transposing a database table to avoid redundancies

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a database table with 2 columns as below:

```
IMPORT_ID   EXPORT_ID
SI1313721   SI1440839
SI1313721   SI1440997
SI1313722   SI1440672
SI1313722   SI1440776
SI1313722   SI1441313
```

IMPORT_IDs are getting repeated (SI1313721 - 2 times and SI1313722 - 3 times). I want to transpose this table into

```
SI1313721   SI1440839   SI1440997
SI1313722   SI1440672   SI1440776  SI1441313
```

How do I do  that in MS Access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To transpose to your needs requires a few nuances including numbering the times of repetition then use subqueries:

SomeQuery:

```
SELECT t1.IMPORT_ID, t1.EXPORT_ID 
   (SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM TableName AS t2
    WHERE t1.EXPORT_ID >= t2.EXPORT_ID 
     AND t1.IMPORT_ID = t2.EXPORT_ID) AS IDCount
FROM TableName AS t1;
```

TransposedQuery:

```
SELECT DISTINCT main.IMPORT_ID,
  (SELECT q1.EXPORT_ID FROM SomeQuery AS q1 
   WHERE q1.IMPORT_ID = main.IMPORT_ID AND q1.IDCount= 1) AS EXPORT1,
  (SELECT q2.EXPORT_ID FROM SomeQuery AS q2 
   WHERE q2.IMPORT_ID = main.IMPORT_ID AND q2.IDCount= 2) AS EXPORT2,
  (SELECT q3.EXPORT_ID FROM SomeQuery AS q3 
   WHERE q3.IMPORT_ID = main.IMPORT_ID AND q3.IDCount= 3) AS EXPORT3
FROM SomeQuery AS main;
```

Comment: The first line of **SomeQuery** should probably end in **t1.EXPORT_ID,** ;-)

Comment: Is it up to 3 per row? What if the number is not known?

Comment: Find the max of `IDCount` from first query and add that many number of subqueries (alternatively you can use self-join queries) If quite a bit like 20, consider looping in VBA to dynamically create the querydef.

Answer (score 1):

Transposing with no support for it, and no analytic function either is probably hard to do. Not sure, why you actually need it transposed in the first place. In order to identify the problematic records, you might be able to work along:

```
CREATE VIEW DuplicateImportID AS
  SELECT
    import_id
  FROM SomeTable
  GROUP BY import_id
  HAVING COUNT(export_id) > 1
;

CREATE VIEW ExportIDForDuplicateImportID AS
  SELECT
    D.import_id
    , S.export_id
  FROM DuplicateImportID D
  JOIN SomeTable S
    ON D.import_id = S.import_id
;

SELECT
  *
FROM ExportIDForDuplicateImportID
ORDER BY import_id, export_id
;
```

Sorry - I have no MS Access at hand to verify / get any closer.
See it in action: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f36d8/1)

If you really need it transposed and are stuck with MS Access, you might want to look into:

```
CREATE VIEW DuplicateImportID AS
  SELECT
    import_id
  FROM SomeTable
  GROUP BY import_id
  HAVING COUNT(export_id) > 1
;

CREATE VIEW ExportIDForDuplicateImportID AS
  SELECT
    D.import_id
    , S.export_id
  FROM DuplicateImportID D
  JOIN SomeTable S
    ON D.import_id = S.import_id
;

CREATE VIEW ExportIDForDuplicateImportID1 AS
  SELECT
    import_id
    , MIN(export_id) export_id
    , 1 level
  FROM ExportIDForDuplicateImportID
  GROUP BY import_id
;

CREATE VIEW ExportIDForDuplicateImportID2 AS
  SELECT
    E.import_id
    , MIN(E.export_id) export_id
    , 2 level
  FROM ExportIDForDuplicateImportID E
  LEFT JOIN ExportIDForDuplicateImportID1 E1
    ON E.import_id = E1.import_id
    AND E.export_id = E1.export_id
  WHERE E1.export_id IS NULL
  GROUP BY E.import_id
;

CREATE VIEW ExportIDForDuplicateImportID3 AS
  SELECT
    E.import_id
    , MIN(E.export_id) export_id
    , 3 level
  FROM ExportIDForDuplicateImportID E
  LEFT JOIN ExportIDForDuplicateImportID1 E1
    ON E.import_id = E1.import_id
    AND E.export_id = E1.export_id
  LEFT JOIN ExportIDForDuplicateImportID2 E2
    ON E.import_id = E2.import_id
    AND E.export_id = E2.export_id
  WHERE E1.export_id IS NULL
    AND E2.export_id IS NULL
  GROUP BY E.import_id
;

CREATE VIEW Transposed AS
  SELECT
    D.import_id
    , (SELECT export_id FROM ExportIDForDuplicateImportID1 WHERE import_id = D.import_id) export_id1
    , (SELECT export_id FROM ExportIDForDuplicateImportID2 WHERE import_id = D.import_id) export_id2
    , (SELECT export_id FROM ExportIDForDuplicateImportID3 WHERE import_id = D.import_id) export_id3
  FROM DuplicateImportID D
;
```

as exemplified in this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/22fce/1).
Not sure, MS Access will support this - MySQL does: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/22fce/1).

Please comment, if and as this requires adjustment / further detail.

Comment: MS Access using the Jet/ACE SQL dialect neither uses views (but rather saved query objects) nor the `CREATE VIEW ViewName AS SELECT...` statement. Fortunately, the OP can still consider your solution by saving the SELECT statements as stored queries with same name as views.

Comment: @Parfait Thanks for your support/input! Basically: If this is a one-off or once-a-month job, one might even take the data to MySQL for just this job. Or something along these lines... ... if nothing else works out...

Comment: I am facing errors with 2nd code -`CREATE VIEW ExportIDForDuplicateImportID AS
  SELECT
    D.import_id
    , S.export_id
  FROM DuplicateImportID D
  JOIN SomeTable S
    ON D.import_id = S.import_id
;` Error `Syntax error in FROM caluse`

Comment: @Karvy1 Does `CREATE VIEW ExportIDForDuplicateImportID AS
  SELECT
    D.import_id
    , S.export_id
  FROM DuplicateImportID D, SomeTable S
  WHERE D.import_id = S.import_id
;` work for you, instead?